# Boxing is to Pugilist as Poker is to

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering earlier, when trying to organise a poker game, what the name for a poker player or players is.

If you are in a race (cars, bikes, running etc), you can use "racers" or similar. In a boxing match you could use "Pugilist" or similar. (I'm not sure where pugilist stops being relevant, are you a pugilist in kick-boxing? katate? but that is outside the scope of my question).

There's always "contenders" or "competitors" or "players", but I was after something more specific, more directly related to poker, or at least card games.

Comment: Do you want a fancy term? The label for someone who boxes is 'boxer'. 'card player' or 'poker player' work just fine.

Comment: The wikipedia article on [poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker) simply uses the term "player."

Comment: I am after a fancy term. I've already mentioned that player is more generic than I'm after, and I was ideally after a single word answer.

Comment: @Puffafish was my answer what you were looking for? Or were you looking  for something more specific?

Comment: @JaredKauffman - yours is the closest I've come across so far, I'm leaving it open for now to see if there are any other ideas out there.

Comment: I read that pugilist is *A boxer, especially a professional one* but rest of the question body implies a *general* term for poker players not just professionals. So are you looking for one specifically for professionals or one that covers everything - professionals and amateurs?

Comment: I'm not fussy; professionals, amatures, everything, people who are good, people who are bad at it. I was after a word that got my point across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Rounder**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_poker_terms#rounder)

Rounder is a slang term for someone who is an expert at poker and plays when they know they can win money.

This is most similar to a pugilist, because a pugilist is typically a name for a professional boxer, as a rounder is an expert poker player.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia is not a reliable or authoritative site.

Comment: @AlanCarmack True, but it's getting better in reliability. From my experience with the site, false information is typically removed from the site within minutes of the false edit being made. Would this site be more reliable (considering it's a site on gambling?) [www.pokertips.org/glossary/w/ROUNDER]

Comment: The Wikipedia  "information" on, for example *Romeo & Juliet*, is based on books that are thirty-plus years out of date. The "information" given in its articles about the English language is, in a word, hideously unreliable and inaccurate. Anyway, yes, a link from a reputed poker site is much preferable in my book. But do as you like.

Comment: Rounder is the sort of word I was after. I shall leave it awhile to see if any other ideas come to the surface.

Comment: Is it used on both sides of the ocean?  How does it compare to gambler?

Comment: @aparente001 Not too sure of it's use worldwide.

Comment: According to Google, it's used in Blighty and in the USA. Gambler is a bit more generic than I was after; a gambler bets on events (in games or races or elections), a "rounder" is a gambler at poker.

Comment: A rounder or grinder is a *type* of player. You would not really use it as a general term for all the players.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here OP wants a general term for both amateurs and professionals ...

The terminology will be different for a **tournament** vs a **cash game**.

The former will have an entry fee (the "buy-in") so term like *entrants* or *entries* will apply.

Refer http://www.wsop.com/m/results/  for 2016 WSOP Main Event details:

> BUY-IN: $10,000.
>   ENTRIES: 6,737
>   PRIZEPOOL: $63,340,268

For a cash game there is not a registration so usually they are just called *players*.

Answer (score 1):

[Card Shark](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/card--shark)

is defined at Dictionary.com as an expert card player.